# Jquery button click event not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a jquery sliding effect. The source am getting from jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YNAJZ/68/. Its working fine in jsfiddle. But not working in my local system. Button click event not fired. i spend more times but i could not find why it not working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
   width:100%;
   height:500px;
   background:#ccc;
   position:relative;
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
#left {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    left:0px;
    background:yellow;
}
#right {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:red;
    right:0%;
}
</style>
<script>
$('#Viewstruct,#viewgrid').click(function(){
    alert('enter here');
        if (parseInt($('div#right').css('right'),10) < 0) {
                 // Bring right-column back onto display
                  $('div#right').animate({
                      right:'0%'
                  }, 1000);

                  $('div#left').animate({
                    width:'100%'
                  }, 600);
                } else {

        // Animate column off display.
                  $('div#right').animate({
                      right:'-100%'
                  }, 600);

                  $('div#left').animate({
                    width:'100%'
                  }, 1000);
        }

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="Viewstruct" title="View Structure" rel="tooltip" href="#">View Structure</a><a id="viewgrid" data-original-title="View Grid" href="#" title="View Grid">View Grid</a>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"> LEFTgdsfgsdfgdsfg</div>
  <div id="right"> RIGHT FADASSD ASDAJKSH ASHDK:L JASKDJ ASKLJSDKJA ASKJD KAJSDKJAS LKJDKLAJ LAKSJD AKLJD KASJDK JALSKDJ LKAJSDLK JASDKLJ ASLKDJ AKLSJD LKASJD LKASJD LKJASD KJAS LKASJ DKASJDK JAS KLDJASDKJ ASLK </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can do that also in a way putting it in function then applying an inline event handler in your button for example **<a href="#" onclick="clickme();">**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please put your click function inside ready block

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#Viewstruct,#viewgrid').click(function(){
    alert('enter here');
        if (parseInt($('div#right').css('right'),10) < 0) {
                 // Bring right-column back onto display
                  $('div#right').animate({
                      right:'0%'
                  }, 1000);

                  $('div#left').animate({
                    width:'100%'
                  }, 600);
                } else {

        // Animate column off display.
                  $('div#right').animate({
                      right:'-100%'
                  }, 600);

                  $('div#left').animate({
                    width:'100%'
                  }, 1000);
        }

});

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put you code inside DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` or shorter form: `$(function() {.... });`. This step is used to make sure that the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Your code is working in `jsFiddle` because `jsFiddle` has already done it for you automatically.

Also, when using `jsFiddle` you don't need to link to external jQuery file in the `External Resources`. You can include jQuery by choosing it from the `Frameworks and Extensions` tab.